# PHP - I have Post IDs, Post slugs, and Post Title. If given one, I want to get any of the other two . How can i best store that in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have data like from a blog, with Post ID, title, and slug. All are unique. (this question is simplified but basically i have three bits of data)

I *might* represent the data like this

```
$data = array(

1 => array('slug' => 'post1', 'title' => 'title1'),
2 => array('slug' => 'slug123', 'title' => 'a test title'),
3 => array('slug' => 'slugfoo', 'title' => 'etc'),
4 => array('slug' => 'slugbar', 'title' => 'foobar'),


)
```

How should i save that data, and how should I retrieve that data?

Because the most basic way of doing it seems slow:

```
function get_slug_from_id($id) {  //not slow
global $data;
return $data[$id]['slug'];
}

function get id_from_slug($slug) { // seems slow for big array

global $data;
foreach($data as $id => $val ) {
if ($val['slug'] == $slug) {
return $id;
}
}

}

etc ...
```

what tricks should i be using?

Comment: define slow and how big your array gets?

Comment: Having an array of `Post` objects might be better for you.

Comment: Assuming this is being saved in a database, the best answer is using SQL for selecting and sorting your data.

Answer (score 0):

> what tricks should i be using?

Trade your memory for CPU - store indexes along with your data. You may think about it as an index in a phone book, for say. Actually, databases are using almost such technique, though more complicated and optimized.

But it's suitable for simple cases like this one too:

```
function build_slug_index() {
    global $slug_index, $data;

    $slug_index = array();

    foreach ($data as $id => $val) {
        $slug_index[$val['slug']] = $id;
    }
}

function get_id_from_slug_indexed($slug) {
    global $slug_index;

    return $slug_index[$slug];
}
```

Then just don't forget to build an index before searching your data.

This simple method gives almost double speed compared to a plain search on my computer:

```
C:\WebDev>php search.php
W/o index - elapsed: 2.7301969528198
W/index - elapsed: 1.3415520191193
```